# Is It Possible for Employers to View the Count of Candidates by Country without First Paying?

Tags: discussion, jobs

As a employer, I am interested to hire developers via StackOverflow Career. But I am not too sure whether my country (Malaysia) has enough developers hanging around at stackoverflow; so I am reluctant to pay for the listing.

Is there anyway I can view the count ( yup, just the count) of candidates by country without first paying?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go to the [employer homepage](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/employer), you can enter certain criteria in the entry fields under **search CVs**, which will then display the number of candidates that meet those criteria. In Malaysia, it looks like there are 12 candidates currently.

Also note there is a no-questions-asked 90-day money-back guarantee, so if you don't find a suitable candidate, all you have to do is request a refund.

Comment: Not too sure how did you get it; but once I click search at this [page](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/employer/search), it takes me to billing [page](https://careers.stackoverflow.com/billing/employers). So annoying!

Comment: if you don't submit the form on that page (or the one @waiwai933 posted), the number of candidates on the right hand side of the page will be updated via AJAX as you enter criteria.  It's a bit slow though and the indicator that it's doing anything is a bit subtle...